# Ubuntu 17.04 - PHP 5.6 and 7.0

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-7, php-5.6

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 with PHP 7 installed. Now, I have another need for some older projects, is it possible to keep two versions of PHP installed on my workstation? If yes, how could I toggle the X and Y version on / off.

Comment: You can do it but it's a pain. You're probably better off using a virtual machine or a docker container for the older code.

Comment: This was already asked somewhere else: https://askubuntu.com/questions/50344/how-to-have-two-versions-of-php-installed-and-switch-easily-between-them

Comment: You might be able to do this with nginx

Comment: Multiple versions of php-fpm can be installed and running at the same time. https://serverfault.com/questions/671400/multiple-versions-of-php-through-nginx/671849#671849

Answer (score 0):

You can use php version managers to achieve this.

Maybe try https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew